# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null - when trying to patch the value

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to patch my data from the server to my formGroup
I am using this code

```
  this.fg.controls.treeInfoModel.patchValue({

        treeORpolygonID: value.treeInfoModel['treeORpolygonID'] ,
        quantityOfTrees: value.treeInfoModel['quantityOfTrees'] ,
        treeType: value.treeInfoModel['treeType'] , 
        actionReasonID: value.treeInfoModel['actionReasonID'] , 
        actionReasonDetails: value.treeInfoModel['actionReasonDetails'] ,
        treeDiameter: value.treeInfoModel['treeDiameter'] ,
        treeDiameter2: value.treeInfoModel['treeDiameter2'],
        treeDiameter3: value.treeInfoModel['treeDiameter3'] ,
        treeHigh: value.treeInfoModel['treeHigh'] ,
        treeCanopy: value.treeInfoModel['treeCanopy'],
        treeHealth: value.treeInfoModel['treeHealth'] ,
        treeLocation: value.treeInfoModel['treeLocation'] ,
        treeTypeValue: value.treeInfoModel['treeTypeValue'] ,


        rootProtectedArea: value.treeInfoModel['rootProtectedArea'] ,
        treeValue: value.treeInfoModel['treeValue'] ,
        copyFeasibility: value.treeInfoModel['copyFeasibility'] , 
        closeUpImgGUID: value.treeInfoModel['closeUpImgGUID'] ,
        areaImgGUID: value.treeInfoModel['areaImgGUID'] 


      });
```

my model is build like:

```
export interface FOTreesDetailsModel {
  selectedType: number;
  //exempSurveyModel?: FOExempSurveyModel | undefined;
  foExempSurveyRequestModel?: FOExempSurveyRequestModel | {};
  treeInfoModel?: FOTreeInfoModel | {};
}
```

`

but I'm getting the error :
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
at FormArray.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormArray.patchValue

why?

Comment: patchValue is applied to a FormGroup or to a FormControl. Are you sure that you has a formGroup "fg" with a property "treeInfoMode" that is a FormGroup when you execute the code?

Comment: @Eliseo thank you again! yes I'm sure

Comment: The error talk about a FormArray but I can see it in the code. remember that to use pathValue in a FormArray, the formArrays should to have so many elements as you use in a pathValue, e.g. is your "actionReasonDetails" is a FormArray, the "value.treeInfoModel['actionReasonDetails']" should be an array with so many elements than the actionReasonDetails -perphaf you should make `this.fg.get('treeInfoModel.actionReasonDetails')=new FormArray(value.treeInfoModel['actionReasonDetails'].map(x=>new FormControl(x))` or some like a loop to add FormControls to your FormArray

Comment: @Eliseo ok, will try, thank you!!